# macOS Sierra Bluetooth is skipping

Tags: audio, bluetooth, macos, speakers

As soon as I upgraded to macOS Sierra a few days ago, my Bluetooth playback has been so choppy/buggy that it is entirely unusable. Playback will be as normal for 2-10 seconds, then cut completely for a few seconds, then cut back in, and so on.

I am connected to a Sony Bluetooth speaker, to which I can confirm that other OS X (El Capitan) and Android/iPhone devices can stream audio to without incident.

I do not have any other Bluetooth speakers to test on, but I strongly feel it's the fault of the macOS Sierra machine, not the speaker.

I am not using any 3rd party or custom audio routing internally, it's literally just routing audio output to the Bluetooth speaker as normal. I've already reset SMC and PRAM, doesn't help whatsoever.

Has anyone else encountered this? If this is a genuine bug in macOS Sierra, it seems like a massive oversight.

Comment: i have a sony speakers as well and is experiencing the same problem since installation of the os sierra

Comment: @Caldo Do you have any other non-Sony Bluetooth speakers to test on?

Comment: I have just started experiencing this same problem with two different sets of bluetooth audio devices - Anker earbuds and a Plantronics Focus headset. Both connect just fine, but after about 15-20 seconds the audio stutters significantly. The Plantronics device detects a connection issue and just disconnects. I wasn't having a single problem before today.

Comment: I have similar issues with my Bose headphones, also triggered by the update to Sierra. I have tried many of the documented tricks for improving BT audio quality on prior versions of the OS, and resetting the bluetooth module, all to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

As stated on a different answer, and I am not quite sure why it was downvoted, the first thing to look for is "bluetooth and 2.4 GHz interference". Make a simple test to switch to a 5GHz Wifi network, and try your Sony Bluetooth speaker once again.

Answer (score 0):

No. Bluetooth audio is quite solid for me on Sierra (and High Sierra now).

The first things I would look at are:

- massive CPU usage in case the background audio processes are not able to get enough CPU.
- make sure the audio playing is local and not streamed
- check for faulty / failing hardware
- bluetooth and 2.4 GHz interference

I'm using my AirPods to test bluetooth - they are rock solid even when other bluetooth accessories seem to chop/lag/skip/drop.